# Parse JSON in Swift to Array of Classes

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I want to parse JSON which has the following format:

```
{
"list": {
    "q": "cookie",
    "sr": "28",
    "ds": "any",
    "start": 0,
    "end": 50,
    "total": 6536,
    "group": "",
    "sort": "r",
    "item": [
        {
            "offset": 0,
            "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
            "name": "THE COOKIE DOUGH CAFE, GOURMET EDIBLE COOKIE DOUGH, COOKIES & CREAM, UPC: 850947006012",
            "ndbno": "45095905",
            "ds": "BL"
        },
        {
            "offset": 1,
            "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
            "name": "MELK AND COOKIES, COOKIE DOUGH CLUSTERS CHOCOLATE CHIP COOKIES, UPC: 094922378675",
            "ndbno": "45026487",
            "ds": "BL"
        }]
}
```

I want to get the data in two classes. One class for the items I get in the JSON file and one for the list.

The item class should have the variables offset, group, name, ndbno and ds. Then I want to get all items to an array "items".

The class list would have the variables q, sr, ds, start, end, total, group, sort and the array items.

I want the json structure in the class structure I defined.

Someone knows how to do that? Thanks.

I get my json from a website. The request I get with the following code:

```
//Send Request
    var done = false
    print("Send request")
    var requestResponse = ""
    var parsedResults: AnyObject?

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {// check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {// check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        done = true
        requestResponse = responseString!
        //print("responseString = \(responseString)")


    }
    task.resume()

    //Wait for response
    repeat {
        RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1))
    } while !done
```

Comment: The `repeat { RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1)) } while !done`: Use a closure. Not that. It's not related to your issue, but that's bad code.

Comment: Have you attempted to parse the JSON and create these classes?

Comment: I created the classes but I don't parse it, because it doesn't worked what I did

Comment: @Larme, can you say me how to do that better?

Comment: There are alot of questions and answers on here already which will show you how to parse the JSON. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=swift+parse+json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward in Swift 4

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "list": {
        "q": "cookie",
        "sr": "28",
        "ds": "any",
        "start": 0,
        "end": 50,
        "total": 6536,
        "group": "",
        "sort": "r",
        "item": [
            {
            "offset": 0,
            "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
            "name": "THE COOKIE DOUGH CAFE, GOURMET EDIBLE COOKIE DOUGH, COOKIES & CREAM, UPC: 850947006012",
            "ndbno": "45095905",
            "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
            "offset": 1,
            "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
            "name": "MELK AND COOKIES, COOKIE DOUGH CLUSTERS CHOCOLATE CHIP COOKIES, UPC: 094922378675",
            "ndbno": "45026487",
            "ds": "BL"
            }
        ]
    }
}
"""
```

---

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let list : List

    struct List : Decodable {
        let q : String
        let sr : String
        let ds : String
        let start : Int
        let end : Int
        let total : Int
        let group : String
        let sort : String
        let item : [Item] // should be `items`

        struct Item : Decodable {
            let offset : Int
            let group : String
            let name : String
            let ndbno : String
            let ds : String
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch { print(error) }
```

PS: As already mentioned in the comments: The while loop is awful. Use an asynchronous completion handler

Comment: As usual with a `do - catch` block. I updated the answer.